# Visual Basic random coordinates

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i was trying to write a program that draws circles around the center of the form (creating a larger circle) and i noticed that it isn't really working, the circles are in the wrong coordinates, the following pictures explain what i mean

when the input is 3:
[image: when the input is 3]

when the input is 10:
[image: when the input is 10]

as you see, the circles aren't uniformed, here is the code:

```
Dim center As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Me.Width / 2)
    Dim angels As Integer = 360 / deviceCount
    TextBox1.Text = deviceCount
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To deviceCount
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, Convert.ToInt32(center + 275 * Math.Cos(i * angels)) - 25, Convert.ToInt32(center + 275 * Math.Sin(i * angels)) - 25, 50, 50)
    Next
```

*note: the form is 600*600 and deviceCount is the number in the textbox (the number of circles)

thanks in advance!

Edit:
[image]

Comment: You know `Math.Cos()` takes angles in radians, so you need to use floats and multiply by `Math.PI/180`

Answer (score 3):

The lazy way.

```
Private Sub DrawCircles(ByVal Graphics As Graphics, ByVal Number As Integer, ByVal Radius As Integer)

    Dim Center = New Point(Me.ClientSize.Width \ 2, Me.ClientSize.Height \ 2)
    Dim BigRadius = Math.Min(Center.X, Center.Y) - Radius

    Dim CurrentState = Graphics.Save()
    Graphics.ResetTransform()
    Graphics.TranslateTransform(Center.X, Center.Y)
    Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, -BigRadius, -BigRadius, BigRadius * 2, BigRadius * 2)

    For i As Integer = 1 To Number
        Graphics.RotateTransform(360 \ Number)
        Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, 0, -BigRadius - Radius, Radius * 2, Radius * 2)
    Next

    Graphics.Restore(CurrentState)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, except that some of the circles are drawn outside the form, will edit the post to show you what i mean

Comment: @GSerg I really liked the way you played with the `Graphics` object :)

Comment: Oh dear, never propose code that uses CreateGraphics().  Add the Graphics object as an argument so it can be called from the Paint event handler.

Comment: @HansPassant That is the second reason why it is called the lazy way! I wasn't calling it from the Paint event handler so there it is. Obviously anyone who uses this should use their e.Graphics. Well, okay, I'll amend it.